# Unexpected key assets ((String)) under font

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

fonts:
- family: OpenSans
fonts:
- asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
weight: 700
- asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf

```
- family: Quicksand
  fonts:  
    - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf
      weight: 700
    - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first value is default. From second you can define weight or style. Please try this

```
- family: Quicksand
  fonts:  
    - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
    - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf
      weight: 700
```